# Can knex.js be used without migrations/seeding? Is there something wrong with this knex.js code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

The cannonical way of using knex.js, it seems, is to create migrations to define schema, and then insert into said schema in normal node.js code.

Is there a way to not use migrations? Can I use the `knex.schema.createTable(...)` function from normal node.js code? Is there any documentation on this sort of thing?

EDIT: I originally wrote this question because I thought I couldn't execute `knex.schema.createTable(...)` functions from within my normal code base. Now it seems I can't use knex properly at all from within any code. If I use migrations to generate schema for a SQLite3 database, it works, but I never seem to be able to insert or query data, within migrations or otherwise.

My migrations file:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
    return Promise.all([
        knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists('test', function(table){
            console.log("creating user table");
            table.increments('id');
            table.text('test');
        })
    ]);
};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
    return Promise.all([
        knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('test')
    ]);
};
```

knexfile.js:

```
module.exports = {
    development: {
        client:       "sqlite3",
        connection: {
            filename: "devel.db"
        },
        useNullAsDefault: true
    },
    deployment: {
        client:       "sqlite3",
        connection: {
            filename: "deploy.db"
        },
        useNullAsDefault: true
    }
};
```

And a mocha/chai test I wrote:

```
const chai      = require("chai");
var knex        = require("knex")({ client: "sqlite3", connection: { filename: "devel.db" }, useNullAsDefault: true });

var expect      = chai.expect;

// The tests.
describe("db", ()=> {
    it("Simple connect, query, and destroy.", ()=> {
        knex('test').insert({ test: 'wow' })
        .catch(function(e){
            console.error(e);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sure. You can do it however you want (migrations in knex, migrations in liquibase, tasks in ansible, anything) so long as the DB exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your migration works correctly.  In your test you need to return the knex object for it to be executed.

```
describe("db", ()=> {
  it("Simple connect, query, and destroy.", ()=> {
    return knex('test').insert({ test: 'wow' })
      .catch(function(e){
        console.error(e);
      });
  });
});
```

In answer to the actual question, yes you can.  The code is similar to the migration code but then() or catch() need to be called to execute it.  The Knex documentation sort of covers this but it's not that clear.  Here's an example of modifying the schema outside a migration file:

```
knex.schema.table('test', function (table) {
  table.string('foo');
  table.string('baa');
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I can't think of many times when modifying database schemas without migrations would work better but that depends on your application.